# Safe way to validate file extension in serializer Django

Tags: django, image, django-rest-framework

I created an application where I can store images of products. In the database I store just directions to images which are held in designated folder. In my serializer I need to validate the files names and check if the extensions are photo extensions. I wrote something like this below, is it the best way to checking it? Is there maybe more safe method?

```
ALLOWED_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif"]


class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = [...]


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [..., 'images']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

        for file in self.context['request'].FILES.getlist('images'):
            validate_extension(file.name)
            ...

        return item


def validate_extension(filename):
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].replace(".", "")
    if extension.lower() not in ALLOWED_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            (f'Invalid uploaded file type: {filename}'),
            code='invalid',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add 2 further checks. Firstly, you could validate the mime type of the file e.g. using the `python-magic` package in linux (`python-magic-bin` for windows). Also, you could compare the file size with the desired max file size in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the FileExttention validator

```py
from django.db import models
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel
from .managers import ImageManager, PDFManager
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
import os


def upload_to_pdfs(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(instance.owner.username, 'pdfs', filename)


def upload_to_images(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(instance.owner.username, 'images', filename)


class Owner(TimeStampedModel):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.__str__()


# Create your models here.
class PDFs(TimeStampedModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pdfs")
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    path = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_pdfs,
                            validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])])

    objects = PDFManager()


class Images(TimeStampedModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    path = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_images,
                            validators=[
                                FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'svg']),
                            ])

    objects = ImageManager()
```